# What data structure should I use to store a collection of items in C#?

Tags: c#, data-structures, split

I have following string : `[Value:"Car" - Name:"Manufactor" [Value:"Audi" - Name:"A6"][Value:"BMW" - Name:"M4"]]]`

I need to split the string and save data into suitable data structure. Starting bracket "[" indicates the beginning of the collection, and 
matching ending bracket "]" indicates the end of the collection. The "-" character seperates key and values. So I was wondering what is most 
logical datastructure to use here? Is using a tree good solution? I have splitted the string up in parts, I only need help to choose a logical datastructure.

Thanks!

Comment: there's no single answer to this; the right model is the one that lets you use it in a useful manner - which is entirely specific to your scenario

Answer (score 1):

Using a tree is not a good solution, as you don't have something like branches with multiple leafs in your structure.

Without knowing your use case, I would use a list or an array of Car-Objects, each having a property Name and Manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a sort of tree, or possibly nested dictionaries if there are other types than `Car`. Or a simple dictionary, like; `Dictionary<Manufacturer, List<CarModels>>`

Answer (score 0):

string is not well-formed I guess (3 opening brackets and 4 closing ones)

that makes your string ambiguous, especially with these 3 closing brackets at the end

Comment: His question is about data structure, not parsing error.

Comment: but this could be a tree with one branch and depth 3 or a collection of key-value-pairs depending on the brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the same as what [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) does. It returns a Dictionary(Of String, Object) and Object is either a string or an other Dictionary(Of String, Object).

The best way would be to have proper classes and good property name and store the information.